# After Polyline to Raster conversion empty attribute table in ArcMap10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, convert, line

I have a line feature class (displaying different types of roads) and want to convert this into a raster. For this I used the Polyline to Raster conversion tool, using "type" in the Value field in ArcMap 10.2. I actually get a new rasterlayer, but it is not displayed in the map and when I look at the attribute table it is empty. Only the headings of the coloums are displayed, but no rows. If I use a different Value field for the conversion it is the same. So how do I get all my data in the attribute table after the conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rasters do not have attribute tables which can store independant attribute values. Only one numeric is stored by default, coming from the field that you select.

A workaround in your case is to add one field in your line feature class where you make a copy of your FID field (unique values). You can convert your lines to raster using this new field, [build a raster attribute table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m2000000), then join the information from your feature class to the raster.

However, if you want to run some analysis with your raster data, you should rather convert your lines with one raster per field with relevant information.